# Context to distinguish "we" inclusive versus exclusive

Tags: meaning, pronouns, clusivity

In English, "we" has no [clusivity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/unclear-use-of-the-word-our/15024#15024) - context is needed to determine whether it means we-including-you or we-excluding-you.

What context can a speaker provide to disambiguate without sounding awkward?

I'm wondering in particular how to reword sentences like "We need to meet tomorrow."

Comment: *You and I* for inclusive, *we* + context for exclusive.  That's the best it gets.

Comment: Unfortunately, *you and I* doesn't extend to more than two people. *we* + context is what sparked the question; it was the only phrasing I could think of, but it always sounds awkward to me.

Comment: *You and we*, then.  Sometimes English just is awkward.

Comment: There is not a single solution for *all* the cases that you might encounter. It's too broad: each time you need to see what to do.

Comment: Why it's not "a real question"?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599044/2085)

Comment: 'In linguistics, clusivity  is a grammatical distinction between inclusive and exclusive first-person pronouns and verbal morphology, also called inclusive "we" and exclusive "we".' [[Wikipedia'(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single trick to do this, but I think that context will get you there the vast majority of the time. Consider these rules:

The context includes a group that the speaker is part of but the listener is not -> exclusive we

The context includes a group that the speaker is part of and the listener is part of -> inclusive we

The context does not include a group -> inclusive we

> "You're saying the committee hasn't voted yet?"
>
> "Yeah, we need to meet tomorrow."

vs.

> "Is our team going to sit down and do the calculations before Friday?"
>
> "Yeah, we need to meet tomorrow."

vs.

> "How are you?"
>
> "Fine, but we need to meet tomorrow."

You can clearly determine if 'we' is inclusive or not.

If all else fails, you can easily be more explicit:

> "We need to meet tomorrow. You should be there, too."

Or perhaps less redundantly:

> "We need to meet tomorrow. Be here at 8:00."

Comment: Well, there is one simple trick, which is to list everybody. "We need to meet tomorrow - you, me, and everyone from Human Resources".